Retrieve list of files currently open
I developed a macro to enter info into a website and upload a file into that same app.
During testing a user left one of the attachments open; which caused an issue.
I'd like to add code to get the name of any open file and compare it to the list of attachments.  If an open file matches an attachment,  I would want the macro to stop and display a message to the user that a specific file is open.
How do I get a list of the open file names?
They could be Excel files, Word documents, pdf files, txt files, csv files or any other file type. I have no way of knowing what kind of files the user would attach to the application.
The macro is VBA based but I have used File Scripting Objects in the past.

What do you mean by "a user left one of the attachments open"? Attachment of what? Independent of this aspect, do you want knowing that a file of unknown type is open, only by its name, or its full name? Then, after definition of these "attachments", wouldn't it be better to check if one of them is open instead issuing a list with all open files and then check them against it? Theoretically, all open processes are based on an open file. And one process can handle even more files of the same type...

@FaneDuru,,,,,,,My macro expects all of the files (e.g., attachments) that are going to be uploaded (to be closed and in a specific folder).

@FaneDuru.........In this case the user had the file open on the desktop and received a message that caused her to stop the macro and shut t down.
What I would like to do is get a list of all open files.  Then my macro would compare the file / attachment to this list.  If there is a match, the macro would stop and notify the user that a particular  file / attachment is open and should be closed before starting the macro again.
I'm trying to prevent potential errors where a user has inadvertently left a file/ attachment open before starting a maro.

Please, can you answer all my questions? What attachment(s) are you talking about? Mail attachments? Do you want checking a Full name file if it is open? Or only based on its name, checking all possible paths? For now, please forget about "a list of all open files" and try answering my questions, please. I know how a file can be checked if it is open. Of course, knowing its full name... If this is the case, I can show you how to do it, but I cannot understand what you try doing. Wouldn't it be good to show your code? In this way we will maybe better understand what you try doing...

@FaneDuru......I've tried answering you questions.  I do not have any code.  That is what I'm trying to get to.  For example, a user may have (1) ABC.xls, (2) Invoice1.PDF, (3) Instructions.Doc, and (4) test.csv files open on their desktop.  The front of my macro has a column for files (also called attachments) that need to be uploaded into an app as part of the the process.  What I'm trying to do is get a list of all open files on their desktop and comparing it to the file names in the column in my macro.  If there is a match, then a particular file is opened and I need the user to close it.

@FaneDuru....I appreciate your help........

Once you have the path of the attachment then you can use THIS to check if the file is open or not. Also if I am not wrong, you cannot check if text file is open or not as the file is not locked when you open it. Similarly if the csv is open in notepad, you cannot check if the file is open for editing or not....

BTW it shouldn't be an issue if text file or csv(opened in notepad) are open... For Excel and Word, I have given you the link. Also, I have not tested it for Pdf.

@Siddharth Rout I have a similar function tested for pdf, also. Of course, open in its default application... Only opening files in text editors cannot be identified by this method. In such a case another method can be imagined. Simpler would be to know his default application opening such files. Probably, Notepad, but he must confirm.... He keeps saying about "a list of all open files". And I cannot determine him to show us what he has and in which circumstances he need to check those pseudo attachments...

Can the user have ABC.xls, or C:\Myfolder\ABC.xls?

@FaneDuru...Yes..........The user has to put the path in another column and the file name in a different column

Are you sure that txt files will also be involved? Anyhow, for txt files I am rather sure that it will no matter if the file is open. Please, test this scenario. It does not matter too  much if the path and name are in different columns. I suppose you know how to concatenate them... Then, you said I developed a macro to enter info into a website... Can you share it to show you how to adapt it for preliminarily checking if the file to be uploaded is open?

Workbooks.Count and loop for names, adding to array.  If any matching names are in your list, then do... quick example for you, though I am lost  without example/code that shows your "application" list.

Since you did not share your code, please try the next solution, based on the next suppositions:
The files to be checked exists in column "A:A" and their name in "B:B"
The next code will check if the files from these two columns are open, or not. Returning TRUE in case of being open. It returns in column "C:C", but you can use it in your existing code to check each file before uploading it:
Sub CheckIfFilesAreOpen()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrOp, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2
  
  ReDim arrOp(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    arrOp(i, 1) = IsFileOpen(arr(i, 1) & "\" & arr(i, 2))
  Next i
  
  sh.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arrOp), 1).Value2 = arrOp
End Sub

Function IsFileOpen(ByVal FilePath As String) As Variant
    If Dir(FilePath) = "" Then IsFileOpen = "Wrong file name": Exit Function
    Dim FileNum As Long: FileNum = FreeFile()
    
    On Error Resume Next
     Open FilePath For Input Lock Read As #FileNum
     Close FileNum
     IsFileOpen = Err.number <> 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
As I said in my comment, open txt files cannot be checked with this method, but I am sure that your method of uploading will not be bothered in case they are open, neither.
Basically, you can use the above function in the next way:
  Dim fileFullName
  fileFullName "C:\YourFolder\yourFullFileName.xlsx" 'use the real full file name
  If IsFileOpen(fileFullName) Then _
     MsgBox "The file " & fileFullName & """ is open. Please, close it and run the code after that!": Exit Sub
  ' your existing code uploading files...
  '.......

